# Deformations of nilpotent parts of superalgebras

Tags: homological-algebra, lie-algebras, spectral-sequences, lie-algebra-cohomology

I have two questions concerning some results in the article "Deformations of nilpotent parts of superalgebras" of N. van den Hijligenberg, J.Math.Phys. 35, 1427 (1994); [doi:10.1063/1.530598](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.530598)

After having defined a filtration, the author claims on page 1431 that the initial term of the corresponding spectral sequence is given by $E^{p,q}_1=H^{p+q}_{(-p)}(L_1^{NS};\mathbb{C})\otimes (L_1^{NS})_{(p+m)}$. 
My first question is: How does one get this result? I have the feeling that there are some intermediate steps that have been omitted.

On the same page at the bottom, the author then says: "We calculated the induced differentials of the spectral sequence by computer and obtained the following result:..."
Hence my second question is: How does one compute these differentials by computer? Is it possible to obtain explicit expressions for these differentials?

Comment: Isn't this just the standard spectral sequence associated to a filtered complex?  I learnt this from §14 in Bott & Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology", but I will defer to the experts' reference of choice.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. But if I try to compute $E_1^{p,q}$ in the usual way, I get something like $E_1^{p,q}=H_{(m+p)}^{p+q}(L_1^{NS},L_1^{NS})$, and this would be the cohomology with respect to $\delta_0$ I guess, i.e. the differential on the zeroth page. In the expression $E_1^{p,q}=H_{(-p)}^{p+q}(L_1^{NS},\mathbb{C})\otimes (L_1^{NS})_{(p+m)}$ though, the cohomology is taken with respect to $\delta$, the differential of the complex $C^*(L_1^{NS},\mathbb{C})$, I think. I don't really see how to get from one to the other? As for the differentials, I don't see at all how to get them.